# A question about changes of the event horizon and the passage of time

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, space

If the event horizon of a blackhole doesn't experience the passage of time how can it change in size when it doesn't experience any time to do so?

Comment: Similar logic could be used to convince you that photons don't move. But they do!

Answer (score 0):

A freely falling observer crossing the event horizon does not notice anything unusual, and certainly experiences the passage of time.

It's true that an observer very far away from the black hole will see light redshift to infinitely long wavelengths as it approaches the event horizon. But this does not prevent events occurring near or on the event horizon.

Comment: “*A freely falling observer crossing the event horizon does not notice anything unusual, and certainly experiences the passage of time.*” - Has anyone tried and reported back?

Comment: @safesphere That's the prediction of GR.

Comment: I see. So your statement is an expectation, not a fact.

Comment: @safesphere My statement is based on a 100+ year-old prediction of GR, in the context of a question that talks about black holes and event horizons. Would you mind explaining how you would answer the question differently?

Comment: I don't feel it's necessary to explicitly add a disclaimer like "assuming the standard description of gravity which like with any scientific knowledge is provisional and can change with further understanding" when answering questions like this, but *of course* my answer assumes the standard description of gravity which like with any scientific knowledge is provisional and can change with further understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!